# Is it possible to acquire the function pointer of a template member function with not all template arguments deduced?

Tags: c++

Considering the code below, is it possible to acquire the function pointer of `operator()` for `Test2` given that you have all its template arguments? For example, say I want a function pointer that points to `operator()<float, double>` where `Args={float}` and `Type2=double`.

```
template<class Type1>
struct Test1 
{
    Type1 value;

    template<class Type2, class ... Args>
    bool operator()(const Type2& type) 
    {
        //... Do something with Args... //
        return type == value;
    }
};

template<class Type1>
struct Test2 
{
    Type1 value;

    template<class ... Args, class Type2>
    bool operator()(const Type2& type) 
    {
        //... Do something with Args... //
        return type == value;
    }
};

int main() 
{
    //OK! 
    auto ptr1 = &Test1<int>::template operator()<float, double>;
    //Not ok! Assuming here that Args = {float, double}, Type2 = ?. Want: Args = {float}, Type2 = double
    auto ptr2 = &Test2<int>::template operator()<float, double>;
}
```

I can see why just providing the template arguments to the function, as usual, doesn't work here. The template arguments are being deduced to be `Args={float, double}` and `Type2` is left, hence a compilation error. This, I think, is evident from the fact that the `Test1` version compiles perfectly fine. Is there a way around this? Thank you.

Comment: `Test1` works because you can specify all of the template paramters.  `Test2` can never work because you can never specify all the template parameters.  Templates aren't a concrete thing, they are just a recipe on how to create a concrete thing.  This means you can't get a pointer to a template, as there is nothing to point to.

Comment: @NathanOliver Seems to me like that is the case, but I wonder if there isn't a workaround involving `operator()<float>(std::declval<double>())` in some way. I can't think of one but I wouldn't be surprised if there was a clever trick to alllow this.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Maybe.  I also believe it is possible to wrap this in a lambda as well.  Without knowing what the OP is trying to do though I can't really offer a concrete alternative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you may try declaring it like this

```
bool (Test2<int>::*ptr2)(const double&) = &Test2<int>::template operator()<float>;
```

or even

```
auto ptr3 = static_cast<bool (Test2<int>::*)(const double&)>(&Test2<int>::template operator()<float>);
```

Comment: I knew there was a way! There's a function I wrote (_disambiguate) https://godbolt.org/z/YxqWTarnj, which does exactly this but it didn't work for this particular scenario, so I discarded the idea of just casting the pointer as a solution. Great stuff.